# Combine pandas data column into a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns of ID's that I want to combine into a single column like the example below. The goal here is to simply replace all 0's in the main column with the values in either ID1 or ID2 AND maintain the score column to the far right.

Note, The Main ID column also has cases where there is already a value as shown in row 3, in that case, nothing needs to be done. Ultimately trying to get a single column as shown in the desired output. Tried using some iterative loop but it was not a pythonic approach.

**Data Table**

```
Main ID ID_1    ID_2   SCORE
0         0    121231   212 
0       54453   0       199
12123   12123   0       185
343434    0    343434   34
2121      0     0       66
0         0     11      565
```

**Desired output:**

```
MAIN ID  SCORE
121231    212 
54453     199
12123     185
343434    34
2121      66
11        565
```

Update, applying the `bfill` method changed all the 'MAIN_ID' numbers into scientific notation like: `3.43559e+06`

Comment: See my solution which maintain the data type as integers.

Comment: Have you looked at my solution ?

Comment: yep! It worked @SeaBean! I left the check mark there! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me, It's simple but functional :D

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'MAIN ID' : [0,0,12123,343434,2121,0], 'ID_1': [0,54453,12123,0,0,0],'ID_2':[121231,0,0,343434,0,11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.iloc[i]['MAIN ID'] == 0:
        if df.iloc[i]['ID_1'] != 0:
            df.iloc[i]['MAIN ID'] = df.iloc[i]['ID_1']
        else:
            df.iloc[i]['MAIN ID'] = df.iloc[i]['ID_2']

df = df.drop(['ID_1', 'ID_2'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `bfill` with `mask`

```
out = df.mask(df.eq(0)).bfill(1)[['Main ID']]
```

Comment: This one worked well, @Beny though it changed the data type i believe of the MAIN_ID numbers (i,e, from 3435590 to 3.43559e+06). Is it possible to also take the score column (just added) into a new dataframe object 'output' ? So i have an dataframe of 2 columns, Main ID and Score?

output = main_df.mask(main_df.eq(0)).bfill(1)[['WORKSPACE_ID']]['SCORE']
output.head()